# Set default selected in dropdown while binding Key-Value pair Object in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have a JavaScript Object in the following form, ([Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YFjfxrC9EamZOVt0ACcu?p=preview))

```
{
  "1" : "John",
  "2" : "Jane",
   .
   .  //Continues.
}
```

I'm binding this Object to a dropdown using AngularJs, here is the html code

```
<select ng-model="CurrentName" ng-options="key as value for(key , value) in Names"></select>
```

And here is the Controller code

```
NamesScript.controller('NamesDropDown', function($scope) {
    var Data = Result.Data;  //This is a Parent Object I'm getting from a REST call. This contains the names Object.
    $scope.Names = Data.names;
    $scope.CurrentName = Data.CurrentName; //Yes getting the CurrentName separately it's NOT present in the Names Object.
//CurrentName Object is in this form {"7":"Foo"}

  }
```

I'm getting the DropDown properly populated except that the default is always blank. How do I set the default value equal to the one I'm getting in CurrentName object?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/A65wLr89sAsYHEpd2L2f?p=preview) i have a sample example for this. you need to specify value key in your controller

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
  <select ng-model="prop.value" ng-options="v for v in prop.values">
  </select>

</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
  $scope.prop = {   "type": "select", 
    "name": "Service",
    "value": "Service 3", 
    "values": [ "Service 1", "Service 2", "Service 3", "Service 4"] 
  };

}
```

Comment: I want the value in the CurrentName object, which is "Foo" as the default selected value.

Comment: i have changed my answer check it

Comment: am i answer you question, let me know

Comment: Sorry can't right now, will try this out as soon as I get home. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the Plunker to my Issue! Please check it out!